# How to split an array index into 2 indexes of that particular index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, split

```
let receipts_array =["Anna 0.4","Peter 0.25","Anna 0.5","Peter 0.5","Peter 0.33"]; //
```

how can I split this array so I can have for example the first index to be just Anna and second 0.4, because i need to sum the numbers and then see who won
**output is just Peter**

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object for summing the values of the names and reduce the keys by checking the values.

```
array.forEach(s => {
    var [k, v] = s.split(' ');
    count[k] = (count[k] || 0) + +v;
});
```

It means take every item of `array` as `s`, split that string by space and use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the array into two items with the name `k` and `v` as key and value.

Then use `k` as key of the object `count`, get this value and if not given take zero as a default value. Then add the value by taking an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for converting the string to a number.

Later assign the sum to the property `k` of `count`.

```js
var array = ["Anna 0.4", "Peter 0.25", "Anna 0.5", "Peter 0.5", "Peter 0.33"],
    count = Object.create(null);
    
array.forEach(s => {
    var [k, v] = s.split(' ');
    count[k] = (count[k] || 0) + +v;
});

console.log(Object.keys(count).reduce((a, b) => count[a] > count[b] ? a : b));
console.log(count);
```

For expected same values, you could return an array with the winner names.

```js
var array = ["Anna 0.4", "Peter 0.25", "Anna 0.5", "Peter 0.5", "Peter 0.33", "Foo 1.08"],
    count = Object.create(null),
    winner;
    
array.forEach(s => {
    var [k, v] = s.split(' ');
    count[k] = (count[k] || 0) + +v;
});

winner = Object
    .keys(count)
    .reduce((r, k) => {
        if (!r || count[k] > count[r[0]]) {
            return [k];
        }
        if (count[k] === count[r[0]]) {
            r.push(k);
        }
        return r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(winner);
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Hello Nina thank you for your help, about the first answer what this mean:
array.forEach(s => {
    var [k, v] = s.split(' ');
    count[k] = (count[k] || 0) + +v;
in plain english

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the posted data sample, you can use the function `split` and function `reduce`.

```js
let receipts_array = ["Anna 0.4", "Peter 0.25", "Anna 0.5", "Peter 0.5", "Peter 0.33"];
var result = receipts_array.reduce((a, c) => {
  var [name, number] = c.split(/\s+/);
  a[name.trim()] = (a[name.trim()] || 0) + +number.trim();
  return a;
}, {});

var winner = Object.keys(result).sort((a, b) => result[a] - result[b]).pop();

console.log(result);
console.log(winner);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array to another array with the itens splitted, like so:

`const resulting_array = receipts_array.map(x => ({name: x.split(' ')[0], points: +x.split(' ')[1]}))`

Then you can sort your resulting array and get the first place.

`const first_place = resulting_array.sort((a, b) => a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1)[0]`

this way you'll have the object with the person with the highest pontuation.

`console.log(first_place.name)`

I'd recommend you to store the info in an array of objects like the one gotten from the map function thoug.

Answer (score 0):

I used **[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to traverse array then split all element by space using **[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and then create one object that will hold value total score for different players and based on that score choose the winner.

```js
var receipts_array =["Anna 0.4","Peter 0.25","Anna 0.5","Peter 0.5","Peter 0.33"];
var x=[],max=-10000,winner;

receipts_array.forEach(function(e){
  var y=e.split(" ");   //split the value
  if(!x[y[0]]){         //check if object with key exist or not
      x[y[0]]=parseFloat(0); //if object not exist create one
  }
  
  x[y[0]]+=parseFloat(y[1]);  // add score of player
  
  if(x[y[0]]>max){    //compare for max score
    max=x[y[0]];
    winner=y[0];
  }
});

console.log(winner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **dictionary** whose keys are the names.

```js
let receipts_array = ["Anna 0.4", "Peter 0.25", "Anna 0.5", "Peter 0.5", "Peter 0.33"];
var result = receipts_array.reduce((obj, c) => {
  var [name, number] = c.split(/\s+/);
  obj[name] = (obj[name] || 0) + parseFloat(number);
  return obj;
},{});

console.log(result);
var winner = Object.keys(result).reduce(function(a, b){ return result[a] > result[b] ? a : b });
console.log('The winner is ' + winner)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```